# How do you add emission to singular faces

Tags: materials

So i'm trying to make assets for a video game and I recently hit an obstacle, and that obstacle was adding emission to a certain face on my 3D model.... Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

With the object in Edit mode:

[image]

- Select the faces you want to be emissive.
- Create a new material slot for your object, if necessary, (**+** on the right)
- Either create a new emissive material (**+** bottom center to copy and overwrite the material in the selected slot, or **New** if the slot is empty), or if the material is already created, select it from the dropdown list (below the **Assign** button)
- Hit the **Assign** button.